# How to create JSON using JSON Simple in Java

Tags: java, json

I have the following json string I want to convert to java code so I can alter it easier and send the newer request but I cannot seem to figure out how to generate it with `JSONObject` and `JSONArray`.

```
["guest_login",{"chips":{"1":2000},"epoch":1552509677,"invested":{"1":2000},"login_id":10,"news":["Welcome to Poker.","Register and get started with 2000 play chips."],"username":"Guest10"}]
```

I get the following output

```
output = ["guest_login",null,null]
```

Here is what I tried so far.

```
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.JSONValue;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray list = new JSONArray();

    list.add("guest_login");
    list.add(new JSONObject().put("chips", new JSONObject().put("1", "2000")));
    list.add(obj.put("epoch", "1552509677"));
    System.out.println("output = " + list.toString());
```

also tried

```
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        json.put("name", "student");

        JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
        JSONObject item = new JSONObject();
        item.put("invested", new JSONObject().put("1", "2000"));
        item.put("login_id", "10");         
        item.put("epoch", "1552509677");
        item.put("chips", new JSONObject().put("1", "2000"));
        item.put("news", new JSONArray().add("Welcome to Poker.").add("Register and get started with 2000 play chips."));
        item.put("username","Guest10");
        json.put("guest_login", new JSONArray().add(item));

        message = json.toString();

        System.out.println("output = " + message);
```

Comment: You don't "convert JSON to Java code." You can read JSON into a Java **object**, but you need to define the object first. It is not clear what you're trying to do here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just run this code and works fine, just change different library:

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

...

        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        JSONArray list = new JSONArray();

        list.put("guest_login");
        try {
            list.put(new JSONObject().put("chips", new JSONObject().put("1", "2000")));
            list.put(obj.put("epoch", "1552509677"));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Fixed it used this code below it works flawlessly!!

```
        list.put("guest_login");
        try {
            obj.put("chips", new JSONObject().put("1", "2000"));
            obj.put("invested", new JSONObject().put("1", "2000"));
            obj.put("login_id", "10");
            JSONArray news = new JSONArray();
            news.put("Welcome to Poker.");
            news.put("Register and get started with 2000 play chips.");
            obj.put("news", news);   
            obj.put("username","Guest10");
            obj.put("epoch", "119677");
            list.put(obj);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: wow thanks, this library should be built in!!! dam what a waste of time I did with Simple JSON

Comment: How would I go about translating the whole thing.. the chips gets chopped off with double }}'s but the epoch is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use POJOs. You can use this online tool http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com/. Once you have your POJO, let say Guest class, you can add whatever you want and if you still need JSONObject, you can get it like this:

```
Guest guest = new Guest();
guest.setChips(//Anything);

JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject( guest );
```

Comment: more classes i rather just hardcode the json in a string and append more json later on for complicated array jsons, no way to do it with any json library I would switch to another json library if its possible

Comment: Is it really necessary to use simple library?